# Google Analytics linker error without AdSupport.framework

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm trying to build my iOS project which includes Google Analytics 3.03a. I've followed all the instructions about using the -force_load linker flags, but unless I include the AdSupport framework I always end up getting this error message when doing my debug build:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGAdvertiserId.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGAdvertisingTrackingEnabledMacro.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGMobileAdwordsUniqueIdMacro.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I try it for my release build I get the same error but for the `armv7` architecture.

Everything I'm reading tells me that if I *do* include the AdSupport framework then my app will get rejected, since I'm not serving ads, so I'm at a loss to know what to do.

This happens both with my actual project, and with a totally new blank test project that literally has no other linker flags:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -force_load ${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
```

I'm not using the Tag Manager at all, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the framework as optional. I submitted apps with Google Analytics without problems.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. You also had the framework added as optional in those apps? How recently did you submit?

Comment: Was it after the "AdSupport ban"?

Comment: Last month, I am reading about this "ban", you should avoid using it until there is an update that removes AdSupport.

Comment: You can look this fix http://weewillrockyou.blogspot.mx/2014/02/ios-fix-for-googleanalytics-303a.html

Comment: Didn't fix it for me, sadly :( I'm just going to try and submit it with the AdSupport framework as 'optional' and pray!

Comment: @andygeers Same problem here, I submit with optionnal AdSupport (I am waiting and pray too) but it seems that any app which is linked to AdSupport and using avdertisingIdentifier will be rejected. The other solution is to change Linker Flags, but we have a lot of compilation error after that : http://weewillrockyou.blogspot.mx/2014/02/ios-fix-for-googleanalytics-303a.html

Comment: FWIW, my update just got approved (20th Feb 2014) with AdSupport linked as optional